# How to enable/disable JButton while selecting some text in JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am creating a simple Notepad application in Java using Swing.

I have created menu options for New, Open, Exit, Cut, Copy, Paste functionalities using JMenu and also created New, Open, Exit, Cut, Copy, Paste icons using JToolBar. For icons I have used JButton component.

My expected scenario:
I want to enable Cut & Copy icons while selecting some text in JTextPane. If no text is selected Cut & Copy icons should be disabled. Sample code please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `CaretListener` to the `Caret` of your text component.

Whenever a `CaretEvent` is generated you can use the `getDot()` and `getMark()` methods of the event.

If the values are the same then no text is selected.

> For icons I have used JButton component.

You should be adding an `Action` to your buttons. Then you can enable/disable the `Action` as required. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on How to Use Actions for more information.

Also, the `DefaultEditorKit` and `StyledEditorKit` will provide many of the Actions you will require. Check out the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for a working example of using these Actions.